# WPF: How to get the true size (Bounding Box) of shapes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm having trouble with getting the actual size (bounding box) of Shapes.

I tried to use both RenderSize and ActualSize but they return values that don't make sense.
However, using these methods for UIElements works great.

if you can help me with this I will be greateful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get the Bounding Box for any `Visual` using `TransformToVisual`

So if you have a `Polygon` defined like this

```
<Canvas Name="canvas">
    <Polygon Name="polygon" Canvas.Left="12" Canvas.Top="12"
             Points="0,75 100,0 100,150 0,75"
             Stroke="Purple"
             Fill="#9999ff"
             StrokeThickness="1"/>
</Canvas>
```

Then you can add a `Border` around its Bounding Box with the following code

```
private void AddBorderForFrameworkElement(FrameworkElement element)
{
    Rect bounds = element.TransformToVisual(canvas).TransformBounds(new Rect(element.RenderSize));
    Border boundingBox = new Border { BorderBrush = Brushes.Red, BorderThickness = new Thickness(1) };
    Canvas.SetLeft(boundingBox, bounds.Left);
    Canvas.SetTop(boundingBox, bounds.Top);
    boundingBox.Width = bounds.Width;
    boundingBox.Height = bounds.Height;
    canvas.Children.Add(boundingBox);            
}
```

However, you may not always get the desired results using this since the Bounding Box will not always be the Bounds for what is actually drawn. If you instead define your `Polygon` like below where you start to draw where x=100 then the Bounding Box will be much larger then what is drawn

```
<Polygon Name="polygon" Canvas.Left="140" Canvas.Top="12"
         Points="100,75 200,0 200,150 100,75"
         Stroke="Purple"
         Fill="#9999ff"
         StrokeThickness="1"/>
```

[image]
*Bounding Box comparison*

Comment: thanks for the answer. However, as you mentioned - I still can't get the correct bounding box for lines. It indeed works for FrameworkElements, yet not for Shapes.

Comment: When loading shapes to the canvas I do not define thier Canvas.SetLeft/SetRight. It automatically presents the shapes in the right place due to the points data. Could this be the problem?

Comment: @Horse Pen: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by `Line`. Do you get any errors or do you get the "wrong" values for the Bounding Box? In the later case I think the problem is that this is actually the bounding box, Visual Studio Designer displays the same thing when selecing it. To get the actual drawn bounds, the only way I can think of is to create a Bitmap from the shape and step trough the pixels.

Comment: px = thisPath.Data.Bounds.X;
                               py = thisPath.Data.Bounds.Y;

Comment: If your shape has negative coordinates, the bounding box from this method will truncate the negative portion.

Answer (score 6):

I've run into this problem too and found that a good way to get the *exact* bounding box for shapes, one that includes the stroke too if there's any, and works for virtually any path I've thrown at it, is the `VisualContentBounds` property from the WPF Visual class.

The problem with this is that it's internal (found it with Reflector), so you can only use it for built-in WPF shapes (since you can't override it outside the assembly) and you need to get it through reflection:

```
    Rect visualContentBounds = (Rect)GetPrivatePropertyValue(myShape, "VisualContentBounds");

    /*...*/

    private static object GetPrivatePropertyValue(object obj, string propName)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");

        Type t = obj.GetType();
        PropertyInfo pi = t.GetProperty(propName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        if (pi == null)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("propName", string.Format("Field {0} was not found in Type {1}", propName, obj.GetType().FullName));

        return pi.GetValue(obj, null);
    }
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is the only solution that will work if the control has NEGATIVE coordinates. eg a line from -100,-100 to 100,100 will get a correct bounding box here, but will not with the other answer.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution does not consider transformations applied to the shape.