# How do you measure the size of a Path object in WPF/Silverlight?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, size, measurement

I am working on a mapping system in WPF and have come across some weird behavior when dealing with Path elements. We have a canvas element with path objects within it that show locations on a map. When I try to measure their size or location through code, their size is always includes their distance from the origin (0,0) and their location is always at the origin. I cannot figure out how to measure the actual visible area of the path itself. Here is an example:

[image: Path Sample]

Now the path as you can see is only roughly a hundred pixels in size, but when reading the AcutalWidth/ActualHeight properties it includes its distance from the top/left corner too. I also tried the .Measure() method on the path and got the same result. Are there any special tools to use that can actually measure the visible area of paths?

Here is the code of this example for reference:

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_Testing_Area.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas x:Name="Wrapper" Width="2185.922" Height="3091.486">
            <Path Fill="#FF9EC99F" MouseLeftButtonDown="Path_MouseLeftButtonDown" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1.5" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeDashCap="Round" StrokeLineJoin="Round" 
                    Data="F1M1501.916,677.412C1480.471,683.851 1457.263,676.647 1443.234,659.196 1441.36,656.865 1439.083,654.889 1436.51,653.362L1436.805,800.23 1533.736,819.855C1537.515,820.62,1541.335,821.166,1545.177,821.49L1501.916,677.412z"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the code behind:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WPF_Testing_Area
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Path_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var path = sender as Path;
            var size = new Size(path.ActualWidth, ActualHeight);
            MessageBox.Show(size.ToString());

            // try to measure the shape
            path.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
            MessageBox.Show(path.DesiredSize.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try subtracting the value of the path's Canvas.Left from the value of path.ActualWidth (same for Canvas.Top and path.ActualHeight).  I'd think that would give you the correct size.

Answer (score 0):

This will prove to be quite tricky because if the path contains an arc and the arc extends beyond the coordinates/point that were used to define the path, it will be hard to calculate a bounding box.

See: [WPF: How to get the true size (Bounding Box) of shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104525/wpf-how-to-get-the-true-size-bounding-box-of-shapes) and [Getting the true visual bounding box of a WPF element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084645/getting-the-true-visual-bounding-box-of-a-wpf-element)

Answer (score 0):

This will be more trick I think.Can you refer these links.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/865tf5y6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

http://forums.silverlight.net/t/22300.aspx/1